# UIBarButton Item with Image Covers UINavigationBar Title

Tags: swift, interface-builder, rightbarbuttonitem

When I try to add a RIGHT bar button item with an image in it (either programatically or via the storyboard), it ends up centred and covers the title (see images below). Why is this?

[image: Nav Bar with Title]

[image: Nav Bar with button covering title]

Comment: You need to add a `UINavigationItem` to your `UINavigationBar`. Then you should be able to add a button using `setRightBarButtonItem:animated:` on your `UINavigationItem`.

Comment: @alain.s I have already done this. Any other ideas why the error would occur? Do you need my code? Thanks.